# Summation over each in grails

Tags: groovy, aggregate-functions

My psudo code for fetching the time taken for each process in a particular job class looks like this.

```
                psteps.each {ProcessingStep pstep ->
    List<ExecutionState> states = ProcessingStepUpdate.findAllByProcessingStepAndState(pstep,ExecutionState.blah)
    states.each{ProcessingStepUpdate psu ->
        use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
            startTime=pc.started
            endTime=psu.date
            timeTaken = endTime-startTime
            println "Time Taken for ${pc.startJobClass} is ${timeTaken} in ${JCType}"                    
        }
    }
}
```

The code is now not in the form of an array/list and therefore I am not able to calculate the total time taken for each jobclass.

here is what I tried

```
use(groovy.time.TimeDuration){
        duration=timeTaken.toArray().sum()
        println "Time taken for ${JCType} is ${duration}"
        println "***********************************************************"
    }
```

any idea what the mistake is? I am new to OOPS world and stuck at it in the last 2 days.

Comment: can you please tell what the error is

Comment: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.time.TimeDuration.toList() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), notify(), wait(), wait(long), is(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timeTaken is not a list, it is a groovy.time.TimeDuration object. Try this:

```
def states = ProcessingStepUpdate.findAllByProcessingStepAndState(pstep,ExecutionState.blah)
def times = []
states.each{psu ->
    use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
        startTime=pc.started
        endTime=psu.date
        timeTaken = endTime-startTime
        times << timeTaken // You add timeTaken to arrayList
        println "Time Taken for ${pc.startJobClass} is ${timeTaken} in ${JCType}"
        println "Total time ${times.sum()}"     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before you do `states.each{` declare a variable `totalTime` that will hold the total time
`def totalTime = 0`

now inside the `each` closure just keep adding `timeTaken` to totalTime
`totalTime += Integer.parseInt(timeTaken)`
try reading a bit of groovy, you can skip a lot of code like `List<ExecutionState> states` and just use `def states`

also after you do `states.each{` you do not need to write `ProcessingStepUpdate psu ->`! you can just do `psu ->` or not even that. Use `it` to reference the current object in the `states` list

Comment: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.plus() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.time.TimeDuration) values: [16.894 seconds]
Possible solutions: plus(java.lang.Character), plus(java.lang.Number), plus(java.lang.String), abs(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), minus(java.lang.Number)`

This is the error I have now

Comment: edited to `totalTime += Integer.parseInt(timeTaken)`  -- i hope you are getting timeTaken as an integer?

Comment: [link]http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeDuration.html
    This is what I use.. and therefore it does not come in Integer format